# Potential energy-Conservative forces

Tags: potential-energy, dissipation, conservative-field

Does potential energy exist because conservative forces exist?

Can a system of objects that interact with dissipative forces have potential energy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Consider the non-conservative force of air resistance. You can lift a rock 20m into the air and drop it and as it is falling it is experiencing both conservative forces (gravity) and non-conservative forces (air  resistance).